# How to delete all characters after a certain character in each line in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that I am reading in and I am trying to delete everything after specific characters such as "[". I have listed the code I have below:

```
while($line = <INFILE>) {
    print "$line \n";
}
```

Some lines will have "[blah blah blah blah]" and I need to delete everything after the first bracket including the first bracket per line, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you tell us more about the file? like some lines have 
"[blah blah blah]" and you want that line deleted? Your best bet would be
to store the lines you do want in a scalar then when the loop terminates write out to a new file.

Comment: The code you included doesn't even _attempt_ to do what you've described.

Comment: Basically I would like to store each line in an array index so that I can search the array. I don't know perl all that well and it seems like declaring and manipulating arrays in perl is much different than say Java.

Comment: Then why not use whichever language you're most familiar with?

Comment: I'd like to learn perl because I want to broaden my knowledge of different languages.

Comment: @Tyler let me know if my answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Seekheart that is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome buddy ;)

Comment: @Tyler yes, the trick is to use a regex capture, you capture everything you want and then store it, thereby deleting everything else.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Since you mentioned you wanted to store the line in an array then do the following.

```
my @arr = ();
while(<INFILE>){
     chomp;
     push @arr, $_;
}
foreach my $item (@arr){
     #process lines as you see fit here
}
```

Comment: I don't know why used the while loop? If store the file into array, simply use `@arr = <INFILE>;`

Comment: You need to remove any trailing white spaces?

Comment: For removing whitespace `foreach my $item (@arr) { chomp $item; ... }`  it will enough. :)

Comment: Great just guess I'm lucky to have been chosen

Comment: This seems not related to the original post at all. Also, you don't need to assign an empty list . `my @arr;` does the same. Also, what's the point of reading a file into an array if you don't know how to process it, as the question implies? Seems wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

To print up to the first occurence of a specific string `$delim`:

```
while (<INFILE>) {
    printf "%s\n", substr($_, 0, index($_, $delim));
}
```

This finds the index of the first occurence of the string and prints from first character (`0`) up to but excluding the index of tat first occurence.

Another option is to use a regex:

```
while (<$fh>) {
    s/\Q$delim\E.*$//m;
    print;
}
```

Note the `\Q` and `\E` delimiters to prevent the regex engine from interpreting e.g. `[` as a regex metacharacter.

Comment: Good point. However, if the line doesn't contain the delimiter, `index($_, $delim)` will return -1 and `substr($_, 0, -1)` will only chomp the newline (if the newline is a single character). Not that it's good practice to rely on such behavior.

Comment: Added a regex solution for completeness.

Comment: The regex answer was exactly what I was looking for, thank you @kba